# onestep checkout continue button wont advance

Tags: magento-1.9

Ok Ive read like every other article resembling my problem and still cant come up with a solution for my personal problem here.

So here is what happened.

Last week i wanted to find out how to change the **url instance** of a button on my **home page**.  So i turned on Template Path Hints to "ON", and Block Hints "ON" under my main web page config/dev. panel.  I hit update config, and it crashed and just went to that white admin login page that you cant actually log into.  Then i saw my frontend was down also.  I googled the problem, and was able to fix it by deleting the entire cache folder in var.  Now after that the next day i noticed i no longer could upload images to edit a static block via the little upload popup box that would usually appear.  I was like ok. So i tried it in google chrome and it worked.  So I just figured it was Firefox acting up.  Now the next day the popup box disappeared in google chrome too.  So i just edited my static blocks via ftp upload.  Now i had a customer try to check out this weekend and was unable to due to this particular error.  No one can seem to click the continue button on this page. fusion checkout page  When i inspect the button element through Firefox i notice it says "function expected"  I think it used to give me a error like "e is not a function" but i cant find that now.  While in the admin panel i would click the blank popup box that would appear when trying to upload a image, and it would give me a very similar or identical error.  So i think something happened when it crashed, but i cant seem to figure it out.  Also i would like to add that i tried switching to the rwd, and default themes, and they are also not working.  Any  help on this guys would be amazing, as im losing business each day this down. Thanks in advance, and ill try and provide any extra detail you might need.

[Fusion Art Glass](https://www.fusionartglass.com)

Magento Version: 1.9.2.4

Comment: Did you not backup your site before making changes in code?

Comment: Have you got backups enabled for the server?

Comment: Actually i took over this site when i started this job.  The previous guy did not have backups enable unfortunately.  I already tried that route, and was pissed to say the least!!!